# PyQt5 how to read/write from/to a QProcess

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 GUI application and would like to execute an external program and display stdout, stderr and stdin of the external program on a QTextEdit widget. I have managed to do so for stdout and stderr. I need help for the stdin of the external process.

Imagine the following snippets

```
       self.te = QTextEdit(self)
       self.te.move(self.x0, 150)
       self.te.resize(self.mainWinWidth - 100, self.mainWinHeight - 200)
```

And the snippet to get QProcess going ...

```
      self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
      self.process.setProcessChannelMode( QProcess.MergedChannels )
      self.process.readyRead.connect(self.readReady)
      # ... and elsewhere I start the sub process like
      os.environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"] = "1"
      self.process.start('./goo', [])
```

and readReady() implemented as:

```
    def readReady(self):
        cursor = self.te.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(cursor.End)
        cursor.insertText(str(self.process.readAll(), 'utf-8'))
        self.te.ensureCursorVisible()
```

And goo(1) is a basic sub process implemented as

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
import sys

for i in range(0,5):
    print(f"============ {i} ===")
    time.sleep(1)

sys.stderr.write("Testing stderr...\n")
print("Enter name:")
name = sys.stdin.readline()
print(f"Got {name}")
```

With that said, I do see stdout and stderr all working ok. I also see "Enter name:" but when I enter "joe" or "moe" on the QTextEdit, nothing happens, ie the back end sub process is still waiting.

So it seems like I need an event handler for the write. That is when the sub-process (via QProcess) waits for input on its stdin, I need to detect that and somehow read that from QTextEdit (from the user) and then feed that to the sub process (i.e write to its stdin).

Think ssh or telnet or xterm. Isn't there any on the shelf widget for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [`write()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write-2) method of QProcess:

```
├── goo
└── main.py
```

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._textedit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
        self._lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self._pushbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Send")
        self._pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self._textedit, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self._lineedit, 1, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self._pushbutton, 1, 1)

        self._process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._process.setProcessChannelMode(QtCore.QProcess.MergedChannels)
        self._process.readyRead.connect(self.on_readReady)

        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        self._process.start(os.path.join(current_dir, "goo"))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_readReady(self):
        cursor = self._textedit.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
        cursor.insertText(str(self._process.readAll(), "utf-8"))
        self._textedit.ensureCursorVisible()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        text = self._lineedit.text() + "\n"
        self._process.write(text.encode())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"] = "1"

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Nice ... so you are using "on_click on send" to take the input from QTextLine and feed it to QProcess.

Comment: A follow up .... what if sub process is very long interactive program with hundreds of line of output and many interactions. And I have an impatient user who would enter presumptuous answer(s) into the TextLine. Wouldn't that confuse the event loop and deliver improper data to handlers ? Is it possible to  disable (or grey out) TextLine until  sub process is ready for input (perhaps via something like writeReady) and then enable the TextLine and disable it again.

Comment: @user3912225 Yes, it is possible. You have to use `self._lineedit.setEnabled(True)` or `self._lineedit.setEnabled(False)` as appropriate. (The same can be done with other widgets such as disabling the button), but that already depends on your logic. My solution is only based on the MRE you have provided.

Comment: I will certainly mark this accepted / correct. One last part , since you have been so nice. Is there such an event like QProcess.writeReady().

Comment: @user3912225 No, there is not. the writing is done synchronously so a signal is not necessary. You could use `waitForBytesWritten(-1)` to be sure it is written but I think it is not necessary.